# How to return a multidimensional array from MVC Controller as JsonResult?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, multidimensional-array

If I try to return a multidimensional .NET array as JsonResult, it returns only a one-dimensional array. Are multidimensional arrays even possible as JsonResult?

```
string[,] MultiDimensionalArray = new string[2, 2] { { "1", "2" }, { "Text1", "Text2" } };

return Json(new
{
    multiDimensionalArray = MultiDimensionalArray
});
```

Comment: why would you have a multidimensional array in jSon?

Comment: I want to return multiple related arrays in one return parameter

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't have a multi-dimensional array at that level of a json object. The top level is one-dimensional, so if you wanted 2 dimensions it would look like this:

```
json = {"text":{"Text1":"1"},{"Text2":"2"}}; 
// then in js
j.text.Text1 //1
```